# Android application not showing up in Play store

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, screen-density, pixel-density

There is an application which is not showing up in google play store for devices like Sony Xperia Z2, One Plus 2 etc with pixel density above 400ppi and less than 500ppi. Previously it was also not showing up for Samsung Galaxy S6 or other higher end devices with pixel density above 500ppi.
But after adding below code it started showing.

```
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="560" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="640" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="640" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="560" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="640" />
```

Can I specify screen density for less than 500ppi in the manifest or is there any rule like we can only give screen density in multiple of something? I have no clue, any help will be great.

Comment: Try this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Comment: @PrerakSola Already tried all these tags and attributes

Answer (score 1):

See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37930628/2557681) for a similar question.

Devices like OnePlus2 and Xperia Z2 fall under the xxhdpi bucket, and have normal screen size.To support these devices add this entry:

```
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
```

If you want to support the xxhdpi bucket for all the screen sizes, add entries with `android:screenDensity="480"` for all the screen sizes.

Android Developer docs doesn't recommend using the `<compatible-screens>` tag. If you want to make your app available for all devices, irrespective of screen size and density, you should remove this tag altogether.